# How would you explain a layman person or a beginner in programming, the bold point of object oriented approach - the SECURITY?

Tags: java, c++, python, objective-c, oop

What does a secure code actually mean? Is it that you cannot make that code do something else, it wasn't supposed to do?

Many of my peers say to migrate to c++ or java as they are more secure because of oops, but when I ask why, they just say, "it's just.......it is".

An example would be so much appreciated. And I am fairly noob in C language, super-noob in c++. (just in case you wonder what complexity of answer would make me understand.)

Comment: I would say security has very little to do with it.

Comment: I dont think oops is more secure.You can say java is more secure than c and cpp, cause java runs on JVM, and c cpp just directly change the memory.but java is secure cares nothing about oops

Comment: I think the best advice is to stop listening to those peers, and ideally find a better job (or internship, or class, or open source project, or whatever) where you can learn useful information instead of nonsense…

Comment: You're in for a lot of oops'es (sic) if you switch to C++ because it's supposedly more "secure". :)

Comment: You have many false assumptions which make answering the question almost impossible.

Comment: We use object oriented language not because of only security but mostly because of the benefits of object orientation. Also security is not provided by language but by framework or run-time environment like JVM, Dot Net etc.

Comment: They want to migrate to java because it's secure? LOL! Zero day exploits are found every month. It's almost impossible to always update JRE for each new exploit.
C is far more secure than java, due to the absence of JVM. The fact that it's easier to write a virus in C doesn't mean that the app you'll build will be less secure.

Comment: Read them this essay http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html

Comment: The problem is that when most programmers say "security" they don't know what they mean. It's become a content-free buzzword.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are vastly confusing the vague term "security" with encapsulation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

"Security", in the sense of protecting sensitive information and preventing attackers from gaining control of your systems and such, has nothing to do with object-oriented programming (though object-oriented programming may certainly be used to implement such security measures).

Answer (score 4):

Below are the parameter which makes any code Secure :

1. Code should do only what was intended.
    Eg: "select * from tablename where id='" + txtUserInputId + "'"
    In above query it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

2. Code must validate all the user inputs.

3. Authorization should be implemented properly other than Authentication.

4. User input data should be sanitized before processing.

5. Session should be managed properly. It also affect the security of code how sessions are managed in .Net or Java or any programming language.

6. Memory must be managed property. One process should not be able to access memory of other process.

7. Database constraints must be validated before any database operation.

8. Configurations must be protected from outside world. For eg: .Net framework does not allow users to see Web.config file. Web.config file may contain sensitive information like DB credentials.

Note: You can say that C#.Net is secure when it comes to query execution. Because it provides CommandParameter which automatically handles user input data for you.

Answer (score 3):

The central point meant by "security" here is that OOP defines a contract (the interface) and separates the implementation. This is called encapsulation. Usually "security" means something else, but I guess that is not what you meant.

That said, consider:

```
class A
{
private:
    int member_var;

public:
    A( int v )
    {
      if( i % 2 == 1 ) throw "odd!";
      member_var = v;
    }
};
```

This allows you to ensure that member_var always contains an even number. Only your methods (the methods of `A`) are allowed to modify `member_var`, so you can guarantee that no user of your class can put an odd number into it.

Compared to other, more dynamic languages an OOP language helps you to check all the rules at compile-time. Dynamic languages usually check at run-time, which might be too late. The static analysis of the compiler helps to prevent bugs *before* they are delivered to a customer.

This is called a (class-)invariant, in case you want to google for more information.